# When to use ?? and ? as placeholders in node-mysql for building a query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am looking at some examples in node-mysql
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

I am confused over when to use ?? and ? as placeholders in constructing a query.

An example is here;

```
var userId = 1;
var columns = ['username', 'email'];
var query = connection.query('SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE id = ?', [columns, 'users', userId], function(err, results) {
  // ...
});

console.log(query.sql); // SELECT `username`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE id = 1
```

How do I know when to use `??` and when to use `?` ?

Comment: The doc tells you that `??` is for identifiers and `?` for values. [Escaping query values](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) and [Escaping query identifiers](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-identifiers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`??` is for identifiers. `?` is for values.

values are variables. identifiers are contents of variables or constants.

For more details, see links below

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-identifiers

Credit goes to t.niese's comment.

Comment: So how does this work in order by. Lets say query - SELECT * FROM blah_table ORDER BY blah_col DESC , the following don't work-  SELECT * FROM blah_table ORDER BY ?? ? . I set ?? to blah_col this is fine but DESC doesn't work when setting for ? .

Comment: `values are variables. identifiers are contents of variables or constants` Isn't that the other way around?.